# std::map<key_type, value_type>::find(different_key_type)

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a map:

```
std::map<TyString, int> myMap;
```

However, in some cases I want to `std::map::find` an entry by making the comparision `TyString == TyStringRef`, i.e.

```
myMap.find(TyStringRef("MyString"));
```

The reason is that TyString wraps a `const char *` that it allocates and deallocates by itself.
However, for only finding an entry I don't like to allocate a new string, instead I want to use only the reference (`TyStringRef` only wraps a const `char *` without allocating or deallocating memory).

Of course I can just convert the `TyStringRef` to a `TyString`, but then I have the memory overhead described above.

Is there an intelligent way to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that `std::map::find` wants to use `operator<`.

Comment: If you can afford paying for the overhead, you might want to convert your `TyStringRef` to a `TyString` before passing to `find` (if it's your type, you can add a conversion operator for this). I guess it's the easiest way to do it, yet not the most efficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `std::map::find` uses `operator<` per default, or a user-defined comparison functor. So unless you overload `operator<` for `TyString` and `TyStringRef`, you can't lookup a key in logarithmic time. With `operator==` being overloaded, you can still lookup in **linear time**, but not using `std::map::find`.

For this, you should use a generic algorithm from `#include <algorithm>`, which is independent from the container classes. It can take *any* type `T` and compares it using `operator==` on the result of `operator*()` of the iterators you pass in.

```
std::find(sequence.begin(), sequence.end(), myKey);
```

However, there is one problem: Since you have a `std::map`, which uses *pairs* for the iterators, *the key-value-pair* will be compared. So you have to use `std::find_if`, which takes a *predicate* instead of a *value* to search for. This predicate should return `true` for the element you are looking for. You want to have the element (pair) for which `first == myKey`, so you end up with a code like this:

```
std::find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [](const std::pair<TyString,int> & pair) {
    return pair.first == TyStringRef("MyString");
};
```

This conceptually works, but it won't make use of the binary tree in `std::map`. So it will take **linear time** compared to logarithmic time of `std::map::find`.

There is an alternative, which looks a bit strange in the beginning, but it has the advantage that it will be a logarithmic time lookup. **It requires you to overload `operator<(TyString,TyStringRef)`.** You can use `std::lower_bound` to find *the first* element which is not less (greater or equal) some element with respect to a given comparison function.

```
std::lower_bound(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), TyStringRef("MyString"),
    [](const std::pair<TyString,int> & entry, const & TyStringRef stringRef) {
        return entry.first < stringRef;
    }
);
```

After the "lower bound" was found, you still have to test if the keys compare equal. If they don't, the element was not found. Since it might be possible that all elements compare less with the element you're looking for, so the returned iterator might be the end iterator, which should not be dereferenced. So the full code becomes this, which is analogous to `std::map::find` and returns the end iterator if the key wasn't found:

```
template<class Map, class KeyCompareType,
         class Iterator = typename Map::const_iterator>
Iterator findInMap(const Map &map, const KeyCompareType &key)
{
    typedef typename Map::value_type value_type;
    auto predicate = [](const value_type & entry, const KeyCompareType & key) {
        return entry.first < key;
    };
    Iterator it = std::lower_bound(map.begin(), map.end(), key, predicate);
    if (it != map.end()) {
        if (!(it->first == key))
            it = map.end();
    }
    return it;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/iym9zf)

Comment: `lower_bound` followed by equality comparison is the way to go, very good idea.

Comment: @TimothyShields Oh, forgot about the final check. Adding this, thanks.

Comment: The first sentence is misleading/wrong.  Even if you overload the comparison operator, The parameter to `map::find` is a `key_type`, and cannot be anything else. (This also applies to all other "finding" members).  Oddly, the rest of the post is quite good

Comment: Why do you have `std::find` in this answer at all?  Just go straight to `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: @MooingDuck You're right. The first paragraph should just address the fact that you can't lookup in logarithmic time using `operator==`, regardless the method and data structure (that's what the second sentence tells; and the first sentence should just tell that unless the OP implements `operator<` for his types, it's not possible in log time).

Answer (score 0):

You could use STLport, which already does this on its own. Maybe other standardlibrary implementations do the same? Alternatively, you could use std::find(), but that would cost you the logarithmic lookup.